# Running the CGI script

Tags: python-3.x

I have written cgi script for the login page in python but I am not familiar with running the CGI script?Please help me by giving the steps to run the script?

Answer (score 0):

Ask your Web host:

1) for a simple "hello, world" script (in Python, I assume) that will work on their    server

2) where you need to store the file (in the server file system)

3)    what you need to name it (ex: index.py or .py or whatever)

4) what permissions the script file needs to have (ask them for a    "setfacl" command you can use), and

5) what the URL will be that    calls it

If any one of those things is even slightly wrong, your script will fail to run. If you get them all right, then your CGI script will return a "Hello, world" web page.

At that point, you modify your script a little bit at a time, testing it every step of the way, until it is doing what you want it to do.